# How to get WSL to connect to the Internet when VPN is on?

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was using both a VPN (Private Internet Access) and Ubuntu WSL1 on Windows 10 with no problem.

Then I upgraded to WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04.  I found that WSL 2 broke my file reloading, so I downgraded the version back to WSL1. I also installed the latest version of my VPN in that time. (I also installed the latest version of VirtualBox (6.1.34), found it didn't work, so I reinstalled version 6.1.3.)

Now WSL1 Ubuntu cannot connect to the Internet when my VPN is enabled. What files and settings must I check to fix this please?

Comment: What does VirtualBox have to do with WSL?

Comment: I have no idea. I added the information in case it affect networks in some way.

Comment: @Richard Can you confirm with a `wsl -l -v` that the Ubuntu version that you are using really was set back to WSL1?  Thanks!

Comment: NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Running         1

Comment: @Richard Remember to @tag in replies so that we get notified.  I'm wondering if you're seeing something like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/589683/432493) where it's really a DNS problem rather than IP.  Can you `ping 8.8.8.8`?  If so, then it's probably DNS, and hopefully that question/answer will help.  Otherwise, we'll keep looking for the cause.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks! I can ping 8.8.8.8, but not google.com or npm.com. So I can go try some of things in the answer you referenced. But - is there a resource you can recommend please that explains how DNS/VPN/nameserver/local network all interact? I would hate to mistakenly bypass my VPN. And I'm lacking fundamental networking knowledge here that I'd like to learn.

Comment: @Richard That's going to depend a lot on your VPN and existing Windows configuration.  My *guess* is that the VPN is changing the Windows resolver (that looks up host names via DNS) when you are connected, which means that the WSL-generated `resolv.conf` isn't working any longer.    With WSL1, when you are connected to your VPN in Windows, you'll be connected in WSL1 - There's really no (easy) way around that.  Changing the resolver in WSL will just impact the server it looks to for hostnames - That was probably a local server (perhaps your router) of some sort when not connected via VPN.

Comment: Ok, setting my `/etc/resolv.conf` to `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and rebooting doesn't work.  I now instantly get `Temporary failure in name resolution` when pinging google.com, instead of it taking a while.

Comment: Ah, you have to set your nameserver to your VPN local address, e.g. 10.0.0.200. Then it works. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#bash-loses-network-connectivity-once-connected-to-a-vpn

Answer (score 3):

Answer is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#wsl-has-no-network-connectivity-once-connected-to-a-vpn

> 1. Take a note of the DNS server of the VPN from doing `ipconfig.exe /all`
> 2. Make a copy of the existing resolv.conf `sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.new`
> 3. Unlink the current resolv.conf `sudo unlink /etc/resolv.conf`
> 4. `sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf.new /etc/resolv.conf`
> 5. Edit `/etc/wsl.conf` and add this content to the file. (More info on this set up can be found in [Advanced settings configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config))
>
> ```
> [network]
> generateResolvConf=false
> ```
>
> 6. Open /etc/resolv.conf and
>
>    a. Delete the first line from the file which has a comment describing automatic generation
>
>    b. Add the DNS entry from (1) above as the very first entry in the list of DNS servers.
>    c. Close the file.
>
> Once you have disconnected the VPN, you will have to revert the
> changes to /etc/resolv.conf. To do this, do:
>
> 1. `cd /etc`
> 2. `sudo mv resolv.conf resolv.conf.new`
> 3. `sudo ln -s ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf resolv.conf`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your problem but after trying numerous very different things, this was my problem. I had these experimental settings and I am on OpenVPN. I commented those in wsl.conf and everything started to flow.

```
#[experimental]
#networkingMode=mirrored
#dnsTunneling=true
#autoProxy=true
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#wsl-has-no-network-connectivity-once-connected-to-a-vpn

```
WSL connectivity issues with VPNs when Mirrored networking mode is on
Mirrored networking mode is currently an experimental setting in the WSL Configuration. The traditional NAT networking architecture of WSL can be updated to an entirely new networking mode called “Mirrored networking mode”. When the experimental networkingMode is set to mirrored, the network interfaces that you have on Windows are mirrored into Linux to improve compatibility. Learn more in the Command Line blog: WSL September 2023 update.

Some VPNs have been tested and confirmed to be incompatible with WSL, including:

"Bitdefender" version 26.0.2.1
"OpenVPN" version 2.6.501
"Mcafee Safe Connect" version 2.16.1.124
```